# DX CLI and VS Code Extensions

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I've got VS Code 1.30.1 (user setup) installed along with:
Node: 8.9.3

VS Code Extensions: All the ones availble as part of the Salesforce Extensions Pack

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode

DX CLI: sfdx-cli/6.44.0-dead729fb5 (windows-x64) node-v8.9.4

on 64-bit Windows.

Whenever, I try to use the SFDX suggestions provided with CTRL+SHIFT+P, I only get errors stating that the underlying commands are not found.

I do have the following entries in my System path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin
C:\Users\U394282\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
C:\Users\U394282\AppData\Roaming\npm
C:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\bin
C:\Program Files\Git\bin
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin
C:\Program Files\nodejs
C:\Users\myUsername\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\bin
```

If anyone's seen this, any help with a solution would be appreciated. I don't have the issue on a personal machine, just a corporate one where I don't have admin rights :/

Comment: Had similar problem, try reinstalling the extension and also you need to reload extension to activate.

Comment: Tried that multiple times, still didn't help. May have to wait until I can get the whole CLI reinstalled

Comment: Yes I've already tried that

Comment: Can you share your settings.json file too? it'll be in your `.vscode` directory. Specifically looking for the value of `salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home`

Comment: Sure, I currently have that config value at `"salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_192"` with a comma after it